# OpenOCD failed to read memory

Tags: gdb, riscv, openocd, jtag, riscv32

I am trying to debug simple hello world c program in custom RISCV board using OpenOCD. We have installed the RISCV 32bit [toolchain](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain/tree/2024.03.01)

OpenOCD:

```
Info : New GDB Connection: 1, Target riscv.cpu0, state: halted
Warn : Failed to read memory via program buffer.
Warn : Failed to read memory via system bus.
Warn : Failed to read memory via abstract access.
Error: Target riscv.cpu4: Failed to read memory (addr=0x11f70)
Error:   progbuf=failed, sysbus=failed, abstract=failed
Error: Target riscv.cpu4: Failed to read memory (addr=0x11f70)
Error:   progbuf=failed, sysbus=failed, abstract=failed
```

gdb terminal:

```
(gdb) load
Loading section .interp, size 0x1a lma 0x10200
Loading section .hash, size 0x30 lma 0x10220
Load failed
```

I have tried the solution

```
set mem inaccessible-by-default off
```

but it was not worked

Please share the thoughts to fix this issue.